# CSS Grid layout with dynamic height

Tags: css, grid, css-grid, grid-layout

I need to create layout 2x2 blocks with min-width 500px and min-height 300px. (first img).
I can collapse blue block (by click on it) to height 100px and the block which is below must fill the gap and become bigger. The same behaviour if lower block collapsed, the upper will stretch. (second img)
if screen width > 1200, turn it into 4 columns with width:300px, height:600px (third img) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X076j.png)

I tried to do add for parent

```
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-rows:  minmax(300px, 1fr) minmax(300px, 1fr);
            grid-template-columns: minmax(500px, 1fr) minmax(500px, 1fr);
            grid-column-gap: 25px;
            grid-row-gap: 25px;
}
```

and also added

```
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
        .parent {
            grid-template-rows:  minmax(600px, 1fr);
            grid-template-columns:  repeat(4, minmax(300px, 1fr));
        }
    }
```

but I don't know how to implement collapsing

Comment: please suggest other screen resolutions (device sizes) for the first and second image

Comment: `display: grid;` is rigid and wouldn't easily allow columns to have multiple heights, for this behavior you should use `display: flex;`. and this sort of interactivity is done using `JavaScript`.

Comment: @John screen resolutions just 2: less then 1200 ->2x2 and more then 1200 -> 4 columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like below. I added a checkbox to simulate the switch between (1) and (2)

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; /* 2 columns */
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  
  gap: 20px;
  border:1px solid;
  height: 300px;
}
.container > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 20px;
}
.container > div > div {
  flex-grow: 1; /* fill remaining height */
  height: 100%; /* we start with equal div */
  
  background: lightblue;
  font-size: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  /* update the height on toggle */
  input:checked ~ .container > div:first-child > div:last-child,
  input:checked ~ .container > div:last-child > div:first-child {
     height: 80px; 
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; /* 4 columns */
  }
  .container > div {
    display: contents; /* remove inner divs */
  }
  /* rectify the order */
  .container > div:first-child > div:last-child {
    grid-column: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div> 1 </div>
    <div> 3 </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div> 2 </div>
    <div> 4 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works!  display: contents; is game changing! You saved me!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I use the columns property on the parent to make a 2 column layout with the children to be flex containers. This means that when the flex children are clicked, we can use flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis to make the clicked one smaller and the unclicked one automatically grow.

For screen sizes greater than 1200px, I've used a media query to flip the flex container to flex-direction: row which makes your four columns. The only bit that's annoying is that the column layout, the middle section is wider than the other parts. You might be able to fix this with a bit of tweaking

```js
window.onload = () => {
  document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.target.classList.toggle('shrink');
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  columns: 2;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 3px solid black;
  height: 600px;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

[id^="b"] {
  background-color: #00A8F3;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

.shrink {
  flex-basis: 100px;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
 
  .column {
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  }
  
  .container {
    display: flex;
  }
  
  [id^="b"] {
    flex-basis: 300px;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='column'>
    <div id='b1'>1</div>
    <div id='b2'>2</div>
  </div>
  <div class='column'>
    <div id='b3'>3</div>
    <div id='b4'>4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but order is important.
It should be:
 b1 b2 b3 b4
and your option with 2 columns and flex-direction: row when >1200 will not work for me because it would be  b1 b3 b2 b4

Comment: Please look at the picture [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X076j.png)

Comment: Gotcha. I'll have a look tomorrow 